# Dojo filteringSelect and Dojo comboBox - Converter not called

Tags: java, combobox, dojo, xpages, converters

I have problem with dojo filteringSelect and dojo combobox component. I have tried to use both components, but problem is the same. I realized that Converter is never called and I am getting error **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch**, when combobox is filled with values.

```
    <xe:djFilteringSelect id="cbDocumentCategoryListtt"
                    dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox"
                    value="#{compositeData.archiveDocument.documentCategory}"
                    disabled="#{javascript:!compositeData.editMode}">
                    <xe:this.queryExpr><![CDATA[${javascript:"*$\{0}*"}]]></xe:this.queryExpr>

                    <xe:this.converter>
                        <xp:converter
                            converterId="ConverterDocumentCategory">
                        </xp:converter>
                    </xe:this.converter>

                    <xp:selectItems id="selectItems2">
                        <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:try{
ControllerDocumentCategory.getAllDocumentCategoryBasedOnLRM(compositeData.archiveDocument.entryDateFrom,compositeData.archiveDocument.entryDateUntil,compositeData.archiveDocument.fund,true)

}
catch(e)
{
var msg="Error: "+ e.toString()+" See log.";
var msgObj = new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage(javax.faces.application.FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, msg);
facesContext.addMessage("",msgObj);
log.logError( e.toString(), null, e ,123,"ccArchiveDocumentBase.xsp",msg);
}}]]></xe:this.value>
                    </xp:selectItems>
                </xe:djFilteringSelect>
```

And this is converter

```
public class ConverterDocumentCategory implements Converter{

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent uiComponent, String text) {
        try
        {  
            if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) 
            {
                return null;
            }
            String msg=LanguageManager.getInstance().getMessageFromPropFile("_object_converter_not_found","WEB-INF/langMsg.properties");
            String [] all=text.split(" - ");
            String name=all[0];
            String codeText=all[1];
            DocumentCategory documentCategory=new DocumentCategory();
            documentCategory.setCodeText(codeText);
            documentCategory.setName(name);
            documentCategory.setActive("");
            List list=DbLotusBroker.getInstance().ftSearch(documentCategory,true);
            if(list.size()==0 || list.get(0)==null)
               {
                   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentInstance().addMessage("", new FacesMessage(msg));
                   throw new Exception(msg);
               }
            documentCategory=(DocumentCategory) list.get(0);

            return documentCategory;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            SRCLogFactory.getInstance().getLog().logError(e);
            context.addMessage("", new FacesMessage("Greška:" +e));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent uiComponent, Object obj) {
        DocumentCategory documentCategory=(DocumentCategory) obj;

        return documentCategory.getName()+" - "+documentCategory.getCodeText(); 
    }

}
```

And in this method I prepare list for filteringselect:

```
public List<SelectItem> getAllDocumentCategoryBasedOnLRM(Object objFrom, Object objUntil, Object objFund,boolean active) {
        sig=new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        sigActive=new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        try
        {

            if(objFrom==null || objFund == null || objUntil==null || ((Fund)objFund).getCodeText()==null ||  ((Fund)objFund).getCodeText().equals(""))
            {
                return sig;
            }
            Fund fund=(Fund) objFund;

            Date date=(Date) objFrom;
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);  


            if(fund.getCodeText().equals("3")){
                LRM lrmm= new LRM();
                lrmm.setCurrent("1");
                lrmm.setFund(fund);
                lrmm=(LRM) DbLotusBroker.getInstance().ftSearch(lrmm, true).get(0);

                if(cal.after(lrmm.getDateFrom()) || cal.equals(lrmm.getDateFrom()))
                {
                DocumentCategory dc=new DocumentCategory();
                LRMGroup lrmGroup = new LRMGroup();
                lrmGroup.setLrm(lrmm);
                dc.setLrmGroup(lrmGroup);
                dc.setActive("1");

                List<Object>list=DbLotusBroker.getInstance().ftSearch(dc, true);
                sig.add(new SelectItem(new DocumentCategory()));
                sigActive.add(new SelectItem(new DocumentCategory()));
                for (Object object : list)
                {
                    DocumentCategory documentCategory=(DocumentCategory) object;
                    sig.add(new SelectItem(documentCategory));
                    if(documentCategory.getActive().equals("1"))
                    sigActive.add(new SelectItem(documentCategory));

                }

            }else{
                getLrmCategory(objFrom, objUntil, objFund, active);

            }
                }
            else{
                getLrmCategory(objFrom, objUntil, objFund, active);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            SRCLogFactory.getInstance().getLog().logError(e);
            context.addMessage("", new FacesMessage("Greška "+e));
        }
        if(active)
            return  sigActive;
        else
            return  sig;
    }
```

Converter is registered in faces-config.xml file:

```
<description>A Converter for document category</description>
    <converter-id>ConverterDocumentCategory</converter-id>
    <converter-class>com.src.converters.ConverterDocumentCategory</converter-class>
  </converter>
```

I think that problem is caused by using component from extension library xe:djFilteringSelect and maybe this component can't work with Converter. Any ideas?

Comment: I never found solution for this problem.